# replace the column values

Tags: php, mysql

Hi im beginner in php and mysql. In my project there is a column named `receipt no` which is auto increment, suppose current receipt no is 108 and I want to add a value with receipt no 90 which is already saved in database with receipt no 90, but it should replace the old receipt 90 with the new receipt no 90 and old receipt no 90 should changed into 91, 91 into 92 and so on till last receipt number it should recrement/adjust automatically. Any ideas?

[image]

mysql code:

```
$query = $this->query("SELECT receipt_no FROM " . KUNKYONGF . " WHERE receipt_no = '$receipt_no'");

if ($query['num_rows'] > 0) {
    return "Receipt No. '" . $receipt_no . "' already exists, it is    now updated please continue..";
}
```

php code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 60%   !important; color:#999999;" name="receipt_no" value="<?php

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `receipt_no` FROM kunkyong_foreign");
        if (mysql_num_rows($query)>0) {
            $data = mysql_query("SELECT max(receipt_no)+1 FROM kunkyong_foreign");
            $res = mysql_fetch_row($data);
            echo $res[0];
            echo $_POST['$res'];
        } else {
            echo 1;
         }
?>" >
```

Comment: Why do you think you need that?

Comment: For this you need to update the  receipt numbers  90 values by checking select query if it's already exist and so on for all next records.

Answer (score 3):

You should never ever touch an autoincrement value. Leave it alone.

Besides, changing receipt numbers makes very little sense by itself. If I made an order and later want to check its details but you change the receipt no - how on the earth I will be able to find it back?

Answer (score 0):

Never ever ever ever play with auto-increment values, you'll lose the tracking of previous order in this context.

Try to solve your problem with another logic.

Good Luck!